# PHP preg_replace stripping

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to delete all comments with their contents with preg_replace().

Example:

```
$mDom =  
<<<HTML
<html>
word1 <!-- word2 --> word3 <!-- word4 --> word5
</html>
HTML;

$mDom = preg_replace('/<!--.*-->/ius', '', $mDom);

var_dump( $mDom );
```

The example above will print: "word1 word5"
I want: "word1 word3 word5"

Comment: Read up on the non-greedy stuff for RegEx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use lazy (non-greedy) quantification:

```
/<!--.*?-->/ius
```

Note the `?` behind `*`. It causes the regex engine to stop as soon as a match is found, not trying to make the match as long as possible.

[Read more about it](http://www.itworld.com/nl/perl/01112001).

---

**EDIT :** You can also use a special modifier `U`:

> **U** (PCRE_UNGREEDY)
>   This modifier inverts the "greediness" of the quantifiers so that they are not greedy by default, but become greedy if followed by `?`.

(PHP Manual: [Possible modifiers in regex patterns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php))

Answer (score 3):

Use a non-greedy version. http://www.skdevelopment.com/php-regular-expressions.php

```
$mDom = preg_replace('/<!--.*?-->/ius', '', $mDom);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of greedy matching.  It matches:

```
<!-- { word2 --> word3 <!-- word4 } -->
```

Add a question mark to encourage laxy matching:

```
'<!--.*?-->'
```